# Segment tree with a matrix

Tags: java, algorithm, segment-tree

I ma trying to find the min value of rows in a matrix depending on a queries.

For example:

```
     0 1 2 3
     _ _ _ _
0 - |2|1|3|2|
1 - |1|3|5|1|
2 - |5|2|1|4|
3 - |2|4|2|1|
```

if I was given a query for row 1, from col 1-2 the min is 3. Etc.

I am confused how to recursively call this function based on the left and right boundaries given.

I can create a segment tree but I am unsure how to implement the left and right into it. Could someone guide me to a link of the algorithm at its full (not some nonsense that people try to explain). Right now I cant find a  good explanation of the algorithm.

Comment: @ruakh I updated sorry

Comment: So will every query specify one row and a range of columns?